# Convert Scala function to Kotlin function

Tags: scala, kotlin

I'm very new to both scala Kotlin and trying my hand at converting some scala code to Kotlin just as a way to get my head around something things.

One this I'm having issues with is converting this scala function to a Kotlin one.

```
def changeXToDigit(value:String): String = {
   value.map {
      case 'X' => random.nextInt(10).toString
      case letter => letter
   }.mkString
}
```

I know there is no mkString equivalent in Kotlin but I figured something like

```
fun changeXToDigit(value: String):String = {
   value.map { it ->
      when(it) {
        'X' -> random.nextInt(10).toString
        else -> it
   }
}
```

might work but IntelliJ complains about it and I'm a bit lost by the error.

```
Error:(11, 45) Kotlin: Inferred type is a function type, but a non-function type String was expected. Use either '= ...' or '{ ... }', but not both.
```

Comment: An interesting thing you can do start with Java and convert to Scala using scala plugin, and also convert Java to Kotlin using the Kotlin plugin (using IntelliJ IDEA OR Android Studio). You can Also go backwards :- Menu > Tools > Kotlin > Show Kotlin Bytecode
Click on the Decompile button
Copy the java code

Comment: In the Scala case you don't even need `mkString` if you emit characters from your mapping function instead of a mix of strings and characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First off, either write

```
fun changeXToDigit(value: String): String = // no curly braces
```

or

```
fun changeXToDigit(value: String): String { // no equals
```

as Kotlin understands `= { }` as defining and returning an closure, not just grouping an expression as in Scala. This is why the error message says "inferred type is a function type".

Next, Scala's `.mkString()` is like Kotlin's `.joinToString()`, although Scala's default separator is `""` and Kotlin's default separator is `", "`.